# Is it the right syntax to add a listener to a component pointed by the loader

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I used syntax I found here [AS3: add event listener to loaded swf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1515869/as3-add-event-listener-to-loaded-swf)

```
    var theLoader:Loader = new Loader();
    theLoader.load(new URLRequest("mySWF.swf"));
    theLoader.addEventListener(CustomEvent.ON_CUSTOM_EVENT,OnCustomEvent);
```

MySWF loads without problem.

It doesn't really returns the class mySWF so I wonder if this is really the right syntax. And actually I don't receive anything.

I am of course dispatching custom event from mySWF.

Flash seems really a nightmare to cope with custom events in practice compared to other platforms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you just need to get a reference to the content loaded by the loader. That works like this:

```
var movieClip:MovieClip;
var loader:Loader = new Loader();
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
loader.load(new URLRequest("mySwf.swf"));

function completeHandler(e:Event):void {
movieClip = MovieClip(loader.content); // this extracts the movieclip.
loader.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
loader = null // prepares the loader for garbage collection.

process();
}

function process():void {
movieClip.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickHandler);
}

function clickHandler(e:MouseEvent):void {
trace("You just clicked your loaded .swf!");
}
```

From here you should just be able to listen for your custom event, too. I'll check back later to see if you're having any luck, I don't have time to build out a full test case right now.

One thing to note - you see that I'm casting loader.content as a MovieClip, that's just because it's a safe, dynamic base class for any loaded .swf. Because MovieClip is dynamic you can attempt to access methods and properties on that class without having them explicitly defined.

If you decide you need more advanced data typing you have a few options. You can create an Interface that gets compiled into both applications (the parent .swf and the child .swf) and then case loader.content as that Interface. Or (and i'm just speculating now, I've never tried this but it SHOULD work...) you can give the child .swf a public property called "myClass" which holds a reference to the base class of that .swf.

Then you'd do what I did above, but in the process() method you'd do something like this:

```
function process():void {
var class:Class = movieClip.myClass as Class;
var myTypedLoadedMovieClip:class = class(movieClip);
trace(myTypedLoadedMovieClip); // this SHOULD work...right?


}
```

As I said, I'll check back later to see if you're having any luck and I'll try to come up with some tests for this!

Comment: You're the greatest Flasher Man it works even with my custom event ;) I just have to correct some mistypo. Thanks very much this has really depressed me for at least 2 days !

Comment: Glad to hear it! Did you go all the way through extracting the document class and casting the loaded .swf as its own document class that way?

Answer (score 1):

your custom event won't get called, because the loader only supports a few predefined events. if you think about it, how could the loader know, when and why he should fire your custom event? it only makes sense to fire predefined events (like Event.COMPLETE, ...). have a look here: [loader events](http://drawlogic.com/2007/09/20/howto-using-loaders-in-as3/).

Comment: The event is fired by some user action well later. So why wouldn't I be able to add custom event ? Also it's not on the loader itself but on the object pointed by the loader.

Comment: If the object on the loader dispatches the event, then ensure that in the event dispatch parameters you enable event bubbling and then this event should be received by your loader, not the loaderInfo. The loaded content will be a direct child of tthe Loader so attach the listener to Loader directly not contentLoaderInfo.

Comment: In case you dont know, event bubbling forces the event to traverse up and down the display list from the child caller and back again. Therefore in your callback you should call the method stopImmediatePropogation() attached to the event in order to prevent the vm from unnecessarily bubbling events and keeping objects alive after you have already reached your destination callback method and therefore no longer require the event instance to be processed.

Comment: OK I'll look at bubbling (I haven't really knowledge about this) but what I failed to understand is why there is no property to get the real instance pointed by the loader so as to attach the event to it not to the loader itself which is just a container ? Because if I can add listener to instance then I wouldn't need to bubble event to loader ? I feel miserable :)

Comment: Pretty much in the callback method e.currentTarget is a reference to the class instance that dispatched the event. So cast that as your custom caller class: var a:MySWF = e.currentTarget as MySWF; or weakly: MySWF(e.currentTarget).customProperty.

Comment: Also see my updated answer about specifically passing a reference inside the custom event.

Comment: OK thank you very much will try all these new suggestions, have a lot of stuff to learn about flash I'm a bit overwhelmed.

Answer (score 1):

Add a parameter to your custom event to include a reference to the instance of the class dispaytching the event. Example:

DispatchEvent(new CustomEvent(CustomEvent.TYPE, bubbles, cancellable, this));

Comment: I have tried as well as put listener to loader and to evt.currentTarget I still fail to receive the event.

Comment: It's probably the way you're dispatching the event. If the Loader or the child swf you load is not added to the stage, then I believe event bubbling will fail since technically the object does not exist on the display list until it or it's parent is added to the stage or a child of stage.

Comment: See this, make adjustments to your code: http://freethemedia.blogspot.com/2007/09/very-important-event-in-as3.html.

Comment: Or alternatively, make your own custom Loader by extending the Loader class and dispatch your custom event from within the Loader once you know the SWF has been loaded. This way you can attach the listener directly to your custom loader and don't have to rely on bubbling, thus removing the dependency of adding the display object or it's children to the stage or a child thereof.