# AS3: let event listener in loaded SWF catch events from parent SWF

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, keylogger

This isn't an exact duplicate of [AS3: add event listener to loaded swf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1515869/as3-add-event-listener-to-loaded-swf), actually it seems to be a mirror situation with non-mirror solution..

I have a test flash file that registers its own listener at first frame's actions.

```
trace("it's going to be OK");
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, aKey);
```

Unfortunately neither line works when .swf is loaded into another movie.
Assuming that `stage` object is wrong for such situations, which object should be used to get listener?

Is it necessary to rewrite loader in parent swf, as said in the linked question?

Answer (score 1):

Try this inside the SWF you're loading:

```
addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAdded);

function onAdded(e:Event):void
{
    stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onKey);
}

function onKey(e:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    trace('key down');
}
```